# How to find point $G$ in this configuration?

Tags: circles

Circle $A$ and circle $B$ intersect at $C$ and $D$. Given that $A = (x_1, 0)$, $B = (x_2, 0)$, and the radii of circle $A$ and circle $B$ are $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively, then how to find  $CG$?

[image]

Comment: Explain what is $r_1, r_2, c_1, c_2$

Comment: @KingTut I'm guessing radius and center for the two circles

Comment: I'm guessing that too, but not sure so I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

You know:
$
r_1\;,\; r_2 \;,\; AB=d
$

let: $AG=x$

Than

$
r_1^2-x^2=CG=r_2^2-(d-x)^2
$

solve this equation  for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- Look for right triangles containing $\overline{CG}$
- Use Pythagoras